# How to synchronize two methods in Android?

Tags: android, opencv

I use OpenCV's `JavaCameraView`to capture images. So it has `onCameraFrame` method.

```
    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) { 
        rgb = inputFrame.rgba();
        if(viewMode == VIEW_MODE_EDGE){
            Mat  mIntermediateMat = new Mat(rgb.size(), rgb.type());
            Imgproc.Canny(rgb, mIntermediateMat, 80, 90);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, rgb, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA, 4);
            mIntermediateMat.release();
        }

        return rgb;
    }
```

That method is always runing and I convert the incoming image to Canny edge and display.

*I implemented a button to copy that Canny image and pass to another activity.* For that I made a global `public static Mat Canny_image;` When the button is pressed the `rgb` image from `onCameraFrame` is copied to `Canny_image`. Then the next activity is called.
My code is

```
ImageCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
                {
                     Canny_image= rgb.clone();  

                }

                final Intent intent = new Intent(ctxt, TextExtraction.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(intent); 
            }                             
        });
```

**Problem:** when i press the button and if canny conversion is finished in `onCameraFrame`method, I receive the canny image (the image with only edges). But if it is not converted yet or half way converted, I receive original rgb image (original rgb image) or half way converted image. How can I make sure I receive only canny image and make sure the conversion process is completed and do cloning as `Canny_image= rgb.clone();`in `ImageCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){};`
Thanks

Comment: I implemented CountDownTimer and will discuss later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To synchronise two methods in Android Java you can use the `synchronized(this)` syntax:

```
Public void OnFrameAvailable() {
    synchronized(this) {
        // Wair for condition false...
        // Flag condition true.
    }
}
```

And

```
Public void ProcessFrame() {
    synchronized(this) {
        // Wair for condition true...
        // Do something with incoming data...
        // Flag condition false
    }
}
```

This would ensure that both methods execute in mutual exclusion, although in general is not a good idea to make a callback wait... If you fully want to decouple both, you should have a thread for processing, with a Looper, and post() a `Runnable` to it from the `OnFrameAvailable()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any knowledge of android but just a suggestion..isn't possible for you to set a flag (e.g set Flag=1) after getting the Canny image `onCameraFrame` method and in the another method you made a check that whether the flag ==1 or not?

```
first()
{
   flag = 0;
   convert to canny;
   flag=1;
}

second()
{
    if(flag ==1)
        try to get the Canny image
}
```

And excuse me if its not possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rgb is a static then one immediate thing to point out is that this will be 4 channel Mat on the call (use inputFrame.gray() if you want a single channel). Canny is expecting a single channel as is the call to CvColor viz the COLOR_GRAY2BGRA conversion type. I don't think that is causing your particular problem but worth checking out.

As onCameraFrame is a callback you could well be processing rgb when another call comes in so rgb could be getting overwritten before you return it in the method. Adding synchronized to the onCameraFrame method should help in that regard but this might impact performance. Alternatively, making rgb local to onCameraFrame should also avoid that particular concurrency issue.

One final thought is rather than do the copy when you click the button, you could do the copy to Canny_image when you finish processing in onCameraFrame so it is always available and onClick will take the current version.